# Custom ViewRenderer<> displays Forms element behind the native control

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app, I have a custom view that derives from ContentView. On iOS and macOS, I would like to replace this view with a native control ([UI|NS]SegmentedControl). So I created a renderer that derives from ViewRenderer and implemented it.

It's working, but there is a flaw. The original Forms control (known as Element within the renderer) is displaying behind the UISegmentedControl. My expectation is that only the native control would be rendered when using ViewRenderer.

Any changes made to the appearance of the Forms element are reflected on the native control, so simply hiding it or making it transparent won't work.

Here's my iOS renderer.

```
public class CustomContentViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomContentView, UISegmentedControl>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomContentView> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null ) {
            if ( Control == null )
                SetNativeControl(new UISegmentedControl(new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three" }));
        }
    }
}
```

CustomContentView here is simply derived from ContentView with a BoxView as content. Here's what it looks like on iOS:
[image: Overlapping controls]

My understanding of renderers is that a custom renderer completely overrides the forms element. Am I missing something big here? Can ViewRenderer<> be used to completely replace a Xamarin ContentView with a native control?

EDIT: In the sample above I'm using a BoxView as a placeholder for the actual cross platform picker I use for UWP. The real control is a StackLayout containing toggle buttons. Here's a screen grab on macOS showing the issue.

[image: macOS version of actual implementation]

In the end, setting Element.Content.IsVisible = false worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can completely replace the ContentView's native control. And you have done so.

What you are seeing is that the (native control for the) *child view* (which you've provided as a BoxView) of the ContentView is *also* displaying.

If you don't want any additional child content, then don't add Content and/or subclass some different class than ContentView. Possible fixes:

- Simply remove the `Content = new BoxView ...` line. I believe that will result in "no child to display". If I'm wrong, then google how to have "no Content".
- You might be able to subclass `View` directly. If not, then you could subclass something simple that usually is used without `Content` - maybe a BoxView.
- Fallback solution: *don't* set `BackgroundColor` on the `BoxView`. Result is an invisible box. (I realize that isn't really what you want: you want to avoid unnecessary creation of views.) [Invisible boxes are occasionally useful as a way to add invisible space in a layout - an alternative to margins.]

---

From your comment, it sounds like you want to "suppress" the given `Content` on one platform, as its role is subsumed by the custom control. To do this, have `IsVisible` property on the child, and set it to `false` on that platform. This will suppress generation of platform controls for the child and its descendents.

CAUTION: Don't try manipulating `Element` properties (such as `IsVisible`) from the custom renderer. This is executing at the wrong moment in the layout/draw sequence. Instead, do from view's code behind or via a Binding. One way to test platform in code is Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceInfo.Platform.

Comment: My example uses an orange BoxView as a simple placeholder for SO. In reality it is a cross platform ContentView containing toggle buttons that perform the same function as a segmented control. So the entire control is drawn behind the native representation. I'd expect it to only render the native control. I'll update the OP to make this clearer.

Comment: @JimMarquardt. It doesn't matter what it is. The point is that it *is the **child view*** of the ContentView. This child is **independent** from the ContentView's Control itself. If you don't want a child view overlaid on the ConventView's Control, then don't add a child view there. What you have defined is **nested controls**. The view hierarchy from XAML gets turned into a control hierarchy on the native platform. The evidence shows that "replacing the element's control" does *not* eliminate the hierarchy of children inside of it. All it does is replace the control that is the "container".

Comment: @JimMarquardt - I think you are confusing the *Content* of the ContentView with the "ContentView" object itself. You are thinking that the *Content* is what is rendered by the platform renderer, and hence would be replaced by the custom *Control* you supply. No, the `Control` of the ContentView is some container control, that you have successfully replaced. The *Content* is not *rendered* by ContentView renderer (though there is measuring/positioning of its *children* in the Xamarin view class, not the renderer) - it is rendered by whatever renderer handles the View you supply as Content.

Comment: I've added to end of  post, to mention hiding content on the platform.

Comment: I added Element.Content.IsVisible = false in OnElementChanged(), and that worked. Thanks for the clarification. I was sure I had tried that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

as per as documentation of Xamarin custom renderers just override Xamarin.Forms appearance and behvoir.
 Here you gave custom content view background orange then in your custom renderer you didn't override it and as I know default background in iOS is transparent so make sense to still in orange color.
Hope to be useful

Comment: I changed the background of Element to match the page background, and the old control is now hiding nicely behind the native control. That works great. I'm just not sure that this is how default renderers handle this (especially because it requires a reference to the background color and wouldn't update it if the background changed). But it works in my scenario.

Comment: OnElementProppertyChanged will provide to you background property changes, and you can override